# Data Processing Extension to connect to a database and call a Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2014

I am implementing a data processing extension to connect a database and call a stored procedure. But when I am using that extension in the report designer I get an error

> Unable to connect to data source DPE. The method or operation is not implemented.

This was written in C# code and I am new to it. I am using SQL Server 2014, Visual Studio 2013 and .Net framework 2.0

Can anyone help please.

Here is my code:

```
namespace DataBaseDPE
{
    public class DBConnection:IDbConnection
    {
        private string mconnstring;
        private string localname = "Database Connection";

        public DBConnection()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DataSetConnection: Default Constructor");
        }
        public DBConnection(string Dconnection)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DataSetConnection Constructor overloaded with Connection String ");
            mconnstring = Dconnection;

        }

        public IDbTransaction BeginTransaction()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return mconnstring;

            }
            set
            {
                mconnstring = value;
            }
        }

        public int ConnectionTimeout
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
        {
            return new DBCommand(this);
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public string LocalizedName
        {
            get 
            { 
                return localname; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                localname = value; 
            }
        }

        public void SetConfiguration(string configuration)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2000;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message, null);
            }
        }
    }

}

        namespace DataBaseDPE
{
    public class DBCommand:IDbCommand
    {
        DBConnection mconnection = null;
        public DBCommand()
        {

        }
        public DBCommand(DBConnection aConnection)
        {
            mconnection = aConnection;
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string CommandText
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public int CommandTimeout
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public CommandType CommandType
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public IDataParameter CreateParameter()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IDataParameterCollection Parameters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public IDbTransaction Transaction
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

    namespace DataBaseDPE
{
    public class DBDataReader:Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader
    {
        private SqlConnection mSql = null;
        private System.Data.DataTable mDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable("ReportTable");
        private SqlCommand msqlcmd = null;
        //private SqlDataReader mreader = null;
        //private SqlDataAdapter madapter = null;

        internal DBDataReader(SqlConnection aSql)
        {
            string conn = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2000;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            mSql = new SqlConnection(conn);
        }
        internal DBDataReader(DBConnection aConnection, SqlConnection aSql, SqlCommand asqlcmd, SqlDataReader areader)
        {
            asqlcmd=msqlcmd;
            aSql=mSql;
            msqlcmd=new SqlCommand("Exec SampleSP",mSql);
           mSql.Open();
           SqlDataReader mreader = msqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
           mreader.Close();
           this.mSql.Close();
        //}
           //internal DBDataReader(DBConnection aConnection, SqlConnection aSql, SqlCommand asqlcmd, SqlDataReader areader);
           //{   
           asqlcmd = msqlcmd;
           aSql = mSql;
           areader = mreader;

        //    internal DBDataReader(SqlDataReader areader, ArrayList rowlist)
        //    {

                SqlCommand SPCmd=new SqlCommand("SampleSP", mSql);
                SPCmd.CommandType=System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataReader reader=SPCmd.ExecuteReader();
                mSql.Open();
                ArrayList rowlist = new ArrayList();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

                reader.GetValues(values);
                rowlist.Add(values);
                }
            //}
            //internal DBDataReader(SqlDataAdapter madapter)
            //{

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }



        //internal void GetTable(DBDataReader aReader)
        //{

        //}

        public int FieldCount
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public Type GetFieldType(int fieldIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetName(int fieldIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetOrdinal(string fieldName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetValue(int fieldIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Read()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the connection needed to use one of the methods that you have not yet implements.

Comment: Well, I noticed that you have several methods throwing `NotImplementedException`, two of which are the `Open` method and the `BeginTransaction` method--of the two, I think the `Open` method is the one you may need to be more concerned about. Try adding an implementation to that method and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement all members (including Connection):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Cristina thanks for the reply, can u give a clue for implementing the members? Because i am new to C# coding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe this article will help you. http://aspalliance.com/837_implementing_a_data_access_layer_in_c